# How to Calculate the factorial of a decimal number in Java?

Tags: java

I did a function to calculate the factorial of a number , but when i writes a decimal number or a character the "mini-application" does not work. How can i calculate the factorial of a decimal and launch a message error to the user when he writes a character .?

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     // BOTON CALCULAR

     String valortextfield = jTextField1.getText();
     int numero = Integer.parseInt(valortextfield);
     Metodos metod = new Metodos();

     BigInteger resultado = metod.factorial(numero);
     String valorAmostrar= resultado.toString();

     jTextArea1.setText(valorAmostrar);

    }
```

the method :

```
public class Metodos {

    public BigInteger factorial (int numero ){
    if ((numero < 0)||(numero >50)) {

        return BigInteger.ZERO;


    } else if (numero==0){

        return BigInteger.ONE;

    } else {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(numero).multiply(factorial(numero-1));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work."?  BTW 51! is not 0.

Comment: I mean it only works with integers , if a introduce a decimal or a character , it launches me an error .

Comment: That is because decimals and other characters are not integers.  What would you like to happen?

Comment: Yes, off course ,i want to know how to manage it also with decimals .

Comment: You have to first work out what you want to happen, then you (with our help) can implement that. What would you like to happen?

Comment: I want to calculate the factorial of an integer or decimal number. with the function that I have now, when I write for example 1.2  does not work because it only works with integers. I would to know how to calculate the factorial of a decimal too.Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can calculate the *Gamma* of a decimal and pretend it is a factorial. Calculating gamma is **far** more complicated and you can only approximate the value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function Are you sure you want to implement such complex maths in BigDecimal?

Comment: Yes that what i found in internet .the gamma function .i am gonna take a look .Thank you for your time .

Comment: If you want to implement this you will have to include a library which supports exponent/powers for BigDecimal.  If you are lucky you may find an implementation for Gamma already written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `try`/`catch` block around your `parseInt()` call and look for `NumberFormatException`.

```
String valortextfield = jTextField1.getText();
try
{
   int numero = Integer.parseInt(valortextfield);
   Metodos metod = new Metodos();

   BigInteger resultado = metod.factorial(numero);
   String valorAmostrar= resultado.toString();

   jTextArea1.setText(valorAmostrar);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   // Show an error message here or whatever is appropriate
}
```

This will not only catch numbers like "123.45", it will also catch other non-number input.

Comment: "that takes a radix."  why?  Wouldn't most people assume base 10?

Comment: My bad.  I was getting mixed up with Javascript parseInt(), which also accepts octal and hex numbers.  I'll edit that out of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scanner

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new  Scanner(System.in);
while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) 
  scanner.next();
System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vd31spb6lr). it's an approximation

Comment: Thanks for adding a link.  It would be helpful to [edit] your answer and give a little more details about  the code shown in the link.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your *factorial* method is fine for only **integer number** but there is a different approach for **fraction** values you have to use **gamma function** for it.

**Approach:**

- First collect the input value
- Validate the input, and there would be one of following three conditions :

  - **non-numeric input:** Show the error message.
  - **integer number:** populate factorial by same way as you have defined in the *factorial* method.
  - **fraction number:** populate factorial using **gamma function** as described bellow-

Following is a simple example to calculate *factorial of a fraction number* using gamma function

**Example of factorial calculation of a fraction number:**

- Formula

[image]

- Here taking a fraction number **1.5!** as an example and apply above formula:

[image]

Useful url for [Gamma Function](https://sites.math.washington.edu//%7Emorrow/336_10/papers/joel.pdf)